# How to trigger the lost focus event for a TextEdit using Robolectric?

Tags: android, testing, kotlin, robolectric

I have a 2 TextEdits on the screen. And they all have a `OnFocusChangeListener` which will check the text in the field, if it's empty it gonna set the `error` property to the error message. It works according to my ad-hoc test.

But I don't know how to verify this using `Robolectric`? I tried this:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class AuthLogDetailActivityUITest {
    @Test
    fun should_show_error_when_no_text_input_when_textInput_lost_focus() {
        val logDetailsActivity = Robolectric.setupActivity(AuthLogDetailsActivity::class.java)

        val quickNameTextEdit = logDetailsActivity.findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.loginDetails_textEdit_quickName)
        val passwordTextEdit = logDetailsActivity.findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.loginDetails_textEdit_password)

        quickNameTextEdit.performClick()
        passwordTextEdit.performClick()

        assertNotNull(quickNameTextEdit.error)
    }
}
```

I tried to mimic the real world, where the user just click the text edit one by one without entering anything.

But in the real world, as soon as the user clicks the `passwordTextEdit`, `quickNameTextEdit` should show the error message.

But the test will always fail because the `quickNameTextEdit.error` is null.

I think it's not the way to trigger that `onFocusChange` event. What is the `Robolectric` way to test this behaviour?

Comment: did you find out? If so, it would be really good if you could answer your own question

Comment: @HuwDavies no. And it’s not been answered in their github repo as well. I finally choose to test ui with espresso and unit test the other parts to do the job.

Comment: that's a shame!

Comment: @HuwDavies it’s a pity. The robolectric fan even downvote this question twice. I wonder why. But seems I am not alone.  So now it gets two votes.

Comment: I think it would be very valuable as a feature. I can see plenty of logic in plenty of apps built into onLossFocus events

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get my `OnFocusChangeListener` triggering by using `.performAccessibilityAction(ACTION_FOCUS, Bundle())`. Hopefully this solves your problem. Your example would look like:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class AuthLogDetailActivityUITest {
    @Test
    fun should_show_error_when_no_text_input_when_textInput_lost_focus() {
        val logDetailsActivity = Robolectric.setupActivity(AuthLogDetailsActivity::class.java)

        val quickNameTextEdit = logDetailsActivity.findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.loginDetails_textEdit_quickName)
        val passwordTextEdit = logDetailsActivity.findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.loginDetails_textEdit_password)

        quickNameTextEdit.performAccessibilityAction(ACTION_FOCUS, Bundle())
        passwordTextEdit.performAccessibilityAction(ACTION_FOCUS, Bundle())

        assertNotNull(quickNameTextEdit.error)
    }
}
```